# Can I use the new folder implementation (plone.app.folder) in Plone 3?

Tags: plone

Plone 4 contains a new folder implementation (in the plone.app.folder package) which is much more efficient for folders with many items. Is it possible to upgrade a Plone 3 site to use this folder implementation without doing a full upgrade of the site to Plone 4?

If so, what steps are required to do so? Any caveats I should be aware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tested a Plone 3.3.5 site with plone.app.folder==1.0.3 (newer version depends on Products.CMFPlone, i.e. Plone 4).

Extend a Plone 3 buildout with this one:

```
[buildout]
extends =
    your-plone3-buildout.cfg

eggs +=
    plone.app.folder==1.0.3

[instance]
zcml +=
    plone.app.folder
```

zcml slug is important because plone.app.folder doesn't use z3c.autoinclude.

After running buildout and launching your instance, install the products as a regular Plone product and migrate existing folder by opening this URL:

http://localhost:8080/plone/@@migrate-btrees

You'll get an output like this one:

```
2011/03/03-17:24:31 migrating btree-based folders from <PloneSite at /plone>:
2011/03/03-17:24:32 intermediate commit (0 objects processed, last batch in 0.289s)...
2011/03/03-17:24:32 processed 0 object(s) in 0.289s (0.290s cpu time).
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! Presumably I need to manually move items from Large Folders back to normal folders then.

Comment: Btw, the Products.CMFPlone 4.0b1 distribution is a stub that doesn't actually contain code, so should work fine with Plone 3.

Comment: I got an error during buildout. Something like "we already have XYZ version". Don't remember. After changing package version everything worked OK.

Answer (score 3):

We used the Plone 4 folders in a Plone 3 site when they were under development, but i don't know if recent development for them have made them depend on other parts of Plone 4.

We still have them running in Plone 3 sites in production, so it *is* possible.

Comment: What are the versions of plone.folder and plone.app.folder that you are using in production?

Answer (score 0):

Not a clue. But Plone 3 has a "Large Folder" which also is based on BTrees and handles large folders well. It's not as slick though. I would use that one under Plone 3, I like to keep my Plone sites as standard as is humanly possible. :-)

Comment: Yes, I know about Large Folders. A client has a use case where they want to customize how ordering is handled, and the new folder implementation makes this much more straightforward as the ordering implementation is looked up as a separate adapter.